# a question on regression analysis ; property of Hat matrix

Tags: regression

Let 1 be the first column vector of the design matrix X. Show that H1=1 for the multiple linear regression case(p-1>1). (H is hat matrix, i.e., H=X(X'X)^-1X')

The followings are my reasoning so far.

Let H=[r1 r2 .. rn]', where rn is a row vector of H.

Then r1*1=1(scalr). (* inner product)

why r1*1 should be 1?

I think prooving H1=H is the same as answering the question above.

But I can not push the thing further.

What property of H should I use?

I know H is idempotent and symmetric.

Do I have to use any other property which I don't know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$H_{n\times k}= X\left(X'X\right)^{-1}X' \Rightarrow X'H = X'$$

The first row of $X'$ is a row of ones, so $\left[X'\right]_{1j}=1$ . Denoting $h_{ij}$ the typical element of $H$, the typical element of the first row of $X'H$ is

$$\left[X'H\right]_{1j} = \sum_{i=1}^n h_{ij} = \left[X'\right]_{1j}= 1 \;\;\forall j$$

But $\left[X'H\right]_{1j}$ is the sum of the elements of the $j$ column of $H$, i.e. it is the inner product of this column with the vector of ones. And this hold for all columns of $H$. $QED$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if we write $H \mathbf{1}=\mathbf{b}$ and premultiply both sides by $X'$, we get $X'\mathbf{1}=X'\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{c}$, where $\mathbf{c}$ is some vector.

$X'\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{c}$ has a unique solution if $X$ has full rank. But we must have full rank of $X$ to even make inverse of $X'X$. So $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{1}$.